# I can't add Firebase to a google project, Invalid Entry

Tags: firebase

I'm trying to add Firebase to an existing google project. Basically I want to migrate the project to Firebase.

**Steps that I followed**

- Go to console.firebase.gooogle.com
- Click import google project
- Select the project (I have owner permission, but I didn't create the project)
- Select the country
- Add firebase

I get the following error:

```
Invalid entry. Please make sure you represent your app accurately.
```

Until today I was getting a generic error such "An error happened, try again", but this has changed.

When I check the browser console for the error, the status code is 400.

Is there anyone who had the same issue and resolved it somehow?

**Note that I tried the following options:**

- Different accounts
- Different browsers
- Incognito mode
- Clear cache / Disable add-ons etc
- Clearly logout/login again

Nothing worked so far and this blocks me to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the error was referring the name wasn't proper in Google console. It was something like "Foo bar bar". Nothing special though. I got support from Firebase and changing name something "foo-bar" solved the problem.

To be honest the error message is too vague. Hopefully this helps someone else.